# Why does gravity couple with a negative dimension?

Tags: general-relativity, renormalization, dimensional-analysis, quantum-gravity, perturbation-theory

I was reading [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/488955/) where it states that

> "gravity does have a coupling with negative dimension and it's the Newton constant"

However, I don't understand at all why Newton's constant leads to gravity coupling with negative dimension. Could it be possible for someone to show why gravity couples with negative dimensions?

Comment: Have you learned about "natural units"? The "negative dimension" of $G$ is $[M]^{-2}$ in the sense of dimensional analysis using natural units where $\hbar=c=1$. The quote isn't talking about spacetime dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @Ghoster's comment, $c=\hbar=1$ implies $1/m=\hbar/(mc)$ is a length, i.e. length and time each have mass dimension $-1$, and $G$ has dimension $\mathsf{L}^3\mathsf{M}^{-1}\mathsf{T}^{-2}$ so has mass dimension $-3-1+2=-2$. By contrast, comparing the GPE $-Gm_1m_2/r$ to its electrostatic counterpart $kq_1q_2/r$ shows $k$, like charge, has mass dimension $0$.

Comment: Thanks! But I just want to ask, the gravitational constant has dimensions $L^3  M^{-1}  T^{-2}$ but why would that then lead to $-3-1+2$?

Comment: @JungwoonSong As I said, length & time each have mass dimension $-1$. Alternatively, note $[G/(c\hbar)]=\mathsf{M}^{-2}$.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

1. Let's for simplicity work in units where $\hbar=1=c$. We will then classify physical quantities $Q$ according to their [mass dimension](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=mass+dimension) $[Q]$, cf. Ref. 1.
2. Recall that [Newton's law of gravitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation) in $d$ spacetime dimensions is
   $$F~=~G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^{d-2}},\tag{1}$$
   up to possible dimensionless constants. The fact that
   $$ [F]~=~2, \qquad [m_1]~=~1~=~[m_2], \qquad [r]~=~-1,\tag{2}$$
   implies that the gravitational constant $G$ has mass dimension $$[G]~=~2-d,\tag{3}$$
   which is negative for $d>2$, cf. OP's title question. See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86508/2451) Phys.SE post.
3. Now, the underlying reason OP asks their question is apparently because this fact leads to the non-renormalizability of perturbative quantum gravity, cf. their linked post. This is e.g. shown in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/724725/2451).

References:

1. M. Srednicki, *QFT,* 2007; Chapter 12. A prepublication draft PDF file is available [here](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emark/qft.html).